# How to make vertical scrolling list view with groups

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I need to create a vertical scrolling list view with grouping enabled as shown below:

[image]

This is what I currently have:

```
<common:VariableSizeListViewWithSelection     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
                                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                              IsItemClickEnabled="True"  
                                              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource summaryViewTemplateSelector}" >


    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,-11,10,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#333333" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>

    <common:VariableSizeListViewWithSelection.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">

            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="LightGray" Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Title}' Foreground="Black" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" Width="300" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>

        </GroupStyle>
    </common:VariableSizeListViewWithSelection.GroupStyle>

</common:VariableSizeListViewWithSelection>
```

But this is not working as expected and it creates a listview with correct grouping but with just one column like this:
[image]

Can you please point me as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you can fit more than 1 item per row in a `WrapGrid` that has a `Width` of 300?

Comment: May I also suggest 1 attribute per line XAML formatting? While it might be fairly subjective if it's better or worse when coding (though it makes diffs easier!) - it is a lot more readable on Stack Overflow.
See this post: http://blog.onedevjob.com/2011/11/07/beginning-winrt-development/

Comment: Hi @FilipSkakun : When I increase the Width of the wrapGrid to say 1500, I still get just one item per row.

Answer (score 0):

We took it offline for a bit and it seems like changing the `ItemsPanel` of the `ListView` to a `StackPanel` make this work. I have a feeling the default `ItemsStackPanel` should still support grouping, but perhaps not with a custom group layout panel. Maybe there is a way to reconfigure a `GridView` to scroll vertically and this could work too.